# Не работает BrowserSync, выдает ошибку при запуске

Tags: gulp

Файл gulp.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('hello', function() {
    console.log('Hello Zell');
});

gulp.task('sass', function(){
    return gulp.src('app/scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass()) // Converts Sass to CSS with gulp-sass
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({
            stream: true
         }))
});

gulp.task('watch', ['browserSync', 'sass'], function(){
    gulp.watch('app/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']); 
    // Reloads the browser whenever HTML or JS files change
    gulp.watch('app/*.html', browserSync.reload); 
    gulp.watch('app/js/**/*.js', browserSync.reload); 
})
```

При вводе в командной строке `gulp watch`, выдает ошибку

> Task 'browserSync' is not in your gulpfile

что не так и как это исправить ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы избавиться от данной проблемы нужно задать еще одну задачу, перед основной по примеру этой:

```
gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
 browserSync.init({
   server: {
     baseDir: 'app'
   },
 })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Конструкция

```
gulp('name', function() {
    // ...
});
```

определяет задачу (task) для Gulp. При этом, первый аргумент (в примере выше `name`) это имя задачи.

В вашем сообщении об ошибке говорится о том, что задача `browserSync` не найдена. И действительно, вы нигде не определяете такой задачи. Как следствие, вам нужно добавить недостающую задачу.

Comment: Я не силен в JS, могли бы Вы подсказать, как должен выглядеть итоговый код ?

Comment: А я откуда знаю, что должна делать задача `browserSync`?

Comment: Следить за изменениям в файлах, и показывать итоговый результат в браузере

Comment: Вы ведь ковыряете какой-то туториал? Может стоить задать вопрос его авторам?

Comment: Я не думаю, что мне ответят, статья за сентябрь 2015.

Comment: Думаю что речь вот об этом: https://css-tricks.com/gulp-for-beginners/ . А если так, то вам всего лишь нужно прочитать руководство **внимательно**. Там есть код для задачи `browserSync`

Comment: Да, Вы правы, после последнего комментария, просмотрел все еще раз и на ответ англоязычном источнике Stackoverflow.